# Cookies are resetting after login

Tags: javascript, cookies

i have set a cookie to count the number of product page visits and is working fine. but after login to the site, cookie is resetting.

client product page

http://www.yougou.com/c-cat/sku-p717303c4c-99942478.shtml#ref=index&po=hot_single601?t=14041172387531571

my cookie "vizNprd" getting reset after login.

please anybody tel me why this is happening and how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using some framework, than it's possible, that session is saved to random variable. And after login, session is looking to your user session variable, that is different from anonymous user. Try something like this:

```
1) $localSession = $this->session;

2) $this->user->login();

3) $this->session = $localSession;
```

Or look for your framework way to pass session variable between login process.

Comment: i dnt have control over the website, client placed our javascript tags on his website to track users.so is this possible to fix this in javascript itself.?

Comment: @Chethi no, you are not possible to change something inside PHP with js.

Comment: what i understood from your point is that, client is resetting cookie from some server side scripts that we dnt have control in JS. am ryt ?